# How to change a single value in a property in a nested object in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: this is the result when i run "npm start"]

i am a beginner starting with react js.
what im trying to do here is change the name of the animal when i press the button underneath the name. ( for instance, change racoon to allegator when i press the button )

this is the code for the parent component.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Child from "./Child";
class Parent extends Component {
  state = {
    animals: [
      { id: 1, name: "racoon", secondName: "allegator", bool: false },
      { id: 2, name: "dog", secondName: "hippo", bool: false },
      { id: 3, name: "cat", secondName: "tiger", bool: false },
    ],
  };
  handleChange = (animal) => {
    console.log(animal);
    const newArray = [...this.state.animals];
    const filterIndex = this.state.animals.findIndex((a) => a.id === animal.id);
    newArray[filterIndex] = {
      ...newArray[filterIndex],
      bool: !newArray[filterIndex].bool,
    };
    this.setState({ animals: newArray });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.animals.map((animal) => (
          <Child
            id={animal.id}
            name={animal.name}
            secondName={animal.secondName}
            change={() => this.handleChange(animal)}
            bool={this.state.bool}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Parent;
```

and the below is the child component

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
class Child extends Component {
  state = {
    animal: this.props.name,
  };
  render() {
    const { change, bool, secondName, name, id } = this.props;

    return (
      <>
        <h1>animal number{id}</h1>
        <p>{bool ? secondName : name}</p>
        <button onClick={change}>이름바꾸기</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Child;
```

i wanted to toggle { bool : !this.state.bool } bool from true to false and apply this to only one object that has been clicked.(onClick).

i was trying to write a logic to setState just one key in one object in an array.

i dont know where i went wrong. could anyone make this button work the way it should? fix my code plzzz

Comment: have you tried passing `bool={animal.bool}` instead of `bool={this.state.bool}`?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the id as the param of `onClick` in Child.jsx.

```
<button onClick={() => change(id)}>이름바꾸기</button>
```

Then use this `id` to change the state.

```
handleChange = (id) => {
  const filterIndex = this.state.animals.map((animal) => animal.id === id ? ({...animal, name: 'racun or any other name', bool: !animal.bool}) : animal);

  this.setState({ animals: newArray });
};
```

Hope this will work. Thanks, brother.

Comment: i am passing the params to onClick on the parent.js page. already done it but not working.. thx for trying to help tho :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Child from "./Child";
class Parent extends Component {
  state = {
    animals: [
      { id: 1, name: "racoon", secondName: "allegator", bool: false },
      { id: 2, name: "dog", secondName: "hippo", bool: false },
      { id: 3, name: "cat", secondName: "tiger", bool: false },
    ],
  };
  handleChange = (id) => {
    let updateBool = this.state.animals.map((animal) =>
      animal.id === id ? { ...animal, bool: !animal.bool } : animal
    );
    this.setState({ animals: updateBool });

    
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.animals.map((animal) => (
          <Child
            id={animal.id}
            name={animal.name}
            secondName={animal.secondName}
            change={this.handleChange}
            bool={animal.bool}
          
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Parent;



import React, { Component } from "react";
class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    const { change, bool, secondName, name, id } = this.props;

    return (
      <>
        <h1>animal number{id}</h1>
        <p>{bool ? secondName : name}</p>
        <button onClick={() => change(id)}>이름바꾸기</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Child;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must replace `bool={this.state.bool}` by `bool={animal.bool}`.

You can simplify the `handleChange` function by using `this.state.animals.map(...)`

```
class Parent extends Component {
  state = {
    animals: [
      { id: 1, name: "racoon", secondName: "allegator", bool: false },
      { id: 2, name: "dog", secondName: "hippo", bool: false },
      { id: 3, name: "cat", secondName: "tiger", bool: false },
    ],
  };

  handleChange = id => {
    const newAnimals = this.state.animals.map(animal => {
      return (id === animal.id) ? 
        {...animal, bool: !animal.bool} :
        animal;
    });
    this.setState({ animals: newAnimals });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.animals.map(animal => (
          <Child
            id={animal.id}
            name={animal.name}
            secondName={animal.secondName}
            change={this.handleChange}
            bool={animal.bool}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    const { change, bool, secondName, name, id } = this.props;

    return (
      <>
        <h1>animal number{id}</h1>
        <p>{bool ? secondName : name}</p>
        <button onClick={() => change(id)}>이름바꾸기</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```